# How can i get my mysql login and password?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm on a mac and am using Mamp.
I 'm just trying to connect to my database through the function mysqli_connect(). 
But it says:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have no idea whatsoever on how to retrieve my login and my password. I've read some posts and apparently it's on a php file: etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php but I cannot find it. 
Thanks.

Comment: ask your local server admin. if you *are* the admin: reset the password.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html - PHPMyAdmin has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Default user and password for MAMP is `root`. Or, you can use your own password by change it manually by run this on Terminal :

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password NEWPASSWORD
```

Comment: Check here for complete tutorial : https://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/changing-mysql-root-user-password-mamp/